# Why I can't remove iTunes and how to remove it?

Tags: itunes, macos

Whenever I run `sudo rm -rf /Applications/iTunes.app`, it is deleted, but after some time it's automatically restored. How can I get rid of iTunes forever without any chance of it coming back?

Comment: I don't think you can. Every OS X update downloads a new version of iTunes, and that restores it. Why do you want to delete it?

Comment: I want to delete it because I don't use it and I absolutely hate when I occasionally launch it by double-clicking an audio file (which I never associated with iTunes — it's iTunes' initiative)

Comment: You can select an audio file, get info and there will be a dropdown to automatically open with selected file. And I guess you could prevent it from running by setting the chmod to rw-rw-rw- or 666

Comment: Yes, but that must be done for every type of file that iTunes supports, and I suspect they are prone to being reset, too… And keeping an application which is not used is a waste of space, in case of SSD this space is also expensive

Comment: Try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/273756/how-to-change-default-app-for-all-files-of-particular-file-type-through-terminal) . It sets default open with to all apps and is located in your user preferences, so it ain't prone to resetting on update

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to prevent it from launching, running

```
sudo chmod 000 /Applications/iTunes.app
```

should do the trick. Needs to be repeated after every OS X/iTunes update, but this also applies for any solutions involving removal of standard applications.

PS: Just to put things into perspective as far as disk space is concerned:

```
root@Mithos:/Applications$ du -sm iTunes.app Chess.app Game\ Center.app Stickies.app Photo\ Booth.app Photos.app 
191 iTunes.app
5   Chess.app
3   Game Center.app
5   Stickies.app
5   Photo Booth.app
31  Photos.app
```

Even on a system with just a 128 GB SSD, squeezing out 200 MB doesn't give you much.

Comment: It works! (at least, prevents launch) But apparently it also breaks updates, I mean, after installing an itunes update, App Store keeps saying that this update is to be installed. Not that I need to install them (I'm not using iTunes anyway), but it would be great to shut up App Store. Still, it's better than nothing.

Comment: Cannot do this on `/Applications/Photos.app` with the latest system updates: `chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Applications/Photos.app: Operation not permitted`. Probably they saw this answer and broken this way.

Comment: that's probably because `Photos.app` has the `restricted` flag. Is there any way to work around that?

Comment: Disable SIP.  Or search the site for how to prevent Photos from auto-starting.

Comment: doesn't work with itunes 12.7

Comment: the question is about how to uninstall it. In my case I want to downgrade itunes and your "answer" is not even useless - it is harmful because the first command still doesn't allow to uninstall it - it disables any action you can perform with this file. I just report you for it

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov Neither the answer nor the thread as a whole are really relevant any longer now that macOS has SIP. With SIP disabled you can easily use `chmod 755` to restore access.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling iTunes is not supported by Apple. Dragging it into the trash and trying to delete the trash will give you a "iTunes can't be modified or deleted because it's required by OS X" message.

Even if you do it manually, it will come back with operating system updates; and you may break certain things like some file associations and iPhone connecting/syncing abilities.

Your best bet is probably just to let it sit there and ignore it.

Comment: I don't mind losing iPhone compatibility (and I'd never buy an iOS-powered device)

Comment: @SargeBorsch I guess you could add a cron-job that runs the delete command every day or something like that. However I'd recommend not to mess with OS-installed apps like that as there tends to be deep integration with other parts of the OS (unfortunately that's sometimes a mess on OS X) and it could interfere with OS updates (imagine a cronjob kicking in while an OS update is installing).

Comment: @SargeBorsch (for a fun time, google for "Remove Stocks app"…)

Answer (score -2):

```
rm -f -r /Applications/iTunes.app
```

removed it for me along with Chess, Game Centre, Photo Booth & Stickies.

You have unload the ituneshelper app first (use activity monitor), I didn't need to as I delete the unnecessary OS X garbage immediately after launch.

It is untrue that it is required by OS X, it is only by required by Apple to sell you stuff.

here's an [AppleScript application](http://www11.zippyshare.com/v/2mZTxjrH/file.html) to automate it, or you can just paste the following into AppleScript Editor and adapt to your taste:

```
(*  Start Apple Peeler Lite and ignore any found entries  *)
display dialog "This will remove unwanted Desktop Pictures, Screensavers, Dictionaries, Languages, Voices & the following apps:


Chess
Games Centre
iTunes
Photo Booth
Stickies


Click OK to start, you will be prompted for your password"

(*  Applications  *)
do shell script "rm -f -r /Applications/Chess.app" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Applications/'Game Center.app'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Applications/iTunes.app" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Applications/'Photo Booth'.app" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Applications/Stickies.app" with administrator privileges

(*  Voices  *)
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/Speech/Voices/Alex.SpeechVoice" with administrator privileges

(*  Dictionaries  *)
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/'The Standard Dictionary of Contemporary Chinese.dictionary'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/'Diccionario General de la Lengua Española Vox.dictionary'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/Dutch.dictionary" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/Italian.dictionary" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/'Korean - English.dictionary'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/Korean.dictionary" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/'Multidictionnaire de la langue française.dictionary'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/Portuguese.dictionary" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/Russian.dictionary" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/'Sanseido Super Daijirin.dictionary'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/'Sanseido The WISDOM English-Japanese Japanese-English Dictionary.dictionary'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/'Simplified Chinese - English.dictionary'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/'Spanish - English.dictionary'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/Thai.dictionary" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Dictionaries/Turkish.dictionary" with administrator privileges

(*  Screen Savers  *)
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Screen Savers'" with administrator privileges

(*  Desktop Pictures  *)
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Abstract.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Isles.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Antelope Canyon.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Lake.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Bahamas Aerial.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Lion.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Beach.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Milky Way.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Blue Pond.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Moon.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Bristle Grass.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Mountain Range.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Brushes.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Mt. Fuji.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Circles.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Pink Forest.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Death Valley.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Pink Lotus Flower.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Desert.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Poppies.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Ducks on a Misty Pond.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Red Bells.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Eagle & Waterfall.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Rice Paddy.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Earth Horizon.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Rolling Waves.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Earth and Moon.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Shapes.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Elephant.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Sky.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Flamingos.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Snow.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Floating Ice.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Floating Leaves.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Underwater.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Foggy Forest.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Wave.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Forest in Mist.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Foxtail Barley.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Frog.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Galaxy.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Grass Blades.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Hawaiian Print.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/Zebras.jpg" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Yosemite 2.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Yosemite 3.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Yosemite 4.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/'Yosemite 5.jpg'" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/.localizations" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/.orderedPictures.plist" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/'Desktop Pictures'/.thumbnails" with administrator privileges

(*  Languages  *)
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/da" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/de" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/es" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/fi" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/fr" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/it" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/ko" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/nl" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/no" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/pt" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/ru" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/sv" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/th" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/tr" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /System/Library/LinguisticData/zh" with administrator privileges

(*  Widgets & Folders  *)
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Widgets" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/iTunes" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Documentation/Applications" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r /Library/Documentation/iPod" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.iTunes" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r ~/Library/Caches/GameKit" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.gamed" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r ~/Library/iTunes" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.iTunes.*.plist" with administrator privileges
do shell script "rm -f -r ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.gamed.plist" with administrator privileges

display dialog "Success!


Unwanted Desktop Pictures, Screensavers, Applications, Dictionaries, Languages & Voices have been removed


Please Restart your Mac" giving up after 15
(*  End Apple Peeler Lite *)
```

Comment: That rm won't have removed Chess.app or the other

Comment: The script works though so maybe it's not a purely terminal command. Please note as Heston Whomanthal said, it is worth opening it up first to make sure it doesn't include things you want to keep). I actually added Photos.app. Script works, can't comment on individual terminal command.

Comment: The usual caveats with downloading code (in this case an application which removes *a lot* more than what the asker is looking for) from unknown sources apply, proceed with care.

Comment: The link is highly suspicious.